# Warning С4715 - Не могу понять, на что ругается компилятор

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Имеется функция перебора динамического списка, записывающая в вектор указатели на те элементы, у которых значение выбранного поля данных совпало с поисковым запросом. По итогам работы она должна возвращать `true`, если вектор имеет хоть один элемент, или `false`, если вектор пуст. Программа, в задуманных мной сценариях, работает корректно, однако меня напрягает предупреждение компилятора (Visual Studio Community 2019) `warning C4715: DynamicList::search: значение возвращается не при всех путях выполнения`. Никак не могу понять, почему он ругается, ведь после завершения цикла функция продолжает своё выполнение. Это из-за вложенных в цикл условий?

```
bool DynamicList::search(unsigned int search_key, unsigned int key_numeric)
{
    DynamicListElement *current_element = this->first_element;

    while (current_element != nullptr)
    {
        if (search_key == NUMBER)
        {
            if (current_element->getNumber() == key_numeric)
            {
                this->search_buffer.push_back(current_element); //std::vector<DynamicListElement*> search_buffer
            }
        }

        current_element = current_element->getNextElement();
    }

    if (this->search_buffer.size() == 0)
    {
        current_element = nullptr;

        return false;
    }
    else if (this->search_buffer.size() > 0)
    {
        current_element = nullptr;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Пробовал также в условиях использовать метод `.empty()`, но предупреждение сохранялось.

**UPD:** Использовал `return !this->search_buffer.empty();` вместо обоих условий в конце.

Comment: return поставьте в конце функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перепишите

```
if (this->search_buffer.size() == 0)
{
    current_element = nullptr;

    return false;
}
else if (this->search_buffer.size() > 0)
{
    current_element = nullptr;

    return true;
}
```

как

```
current_element = nullptr;
return this->search_buffer.size() > 0;
```

Если, конечно, у вас `this->search_buffer.size()` не знаковое и не может вернуть отрицательное значение :)

Comment: Красивое решение! Спасибо, теперь знаю что и так можно. Нет, search_buffer имеет тип **std::vector**.

Comment: Ну вот... Я сначала почти то же самое написал, и только потом заметил этот ответ. Разница только в том, что у меня размер неявно кастится к bool'у.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кстати, еще короче :)

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (this->search_buffer.size() > 0) // условие не выполняется
{
    current_element = nullptr;

    return true;
}
// попадаем сюда и функция заканчивается
```

По логике, если тип размера буфера беззнаковый, то это второе условие избыточно. Первое условие имеет смысл переделеать в `if(this->search_buffer.empty())`, а лучше вообще избавиться от ненужного ветвления:

```
current_element = nullptr;
return not this->search_buffer.empty();
```

Comment: size() может возвращать меньше 0?

Comment: @P1xelGuarD теоритически ничего не мешает `size()` вернуть 0 при повторном вызове, но я не думаю, что компилятор анализирует в глубину

Comment: То есть, по-сути, хватит **If**'а на **size() > 0** и последующего **else**? Понял

Comment: У меня есть перегруженная функция под другой тип данных поискового запроса, в которой используется похожая конструкция, но с **.empty() == true** и **.empty() == false**, но визуалка ругает и её. Хотя, по-сути, **.empty()** не может вернуть ничего, кроме этих двух значений. :/

Comment: @P1xelGuarD Это **единичный** вызов может вернуть только одно из двух значений, а оснований считать, что **повторный** вызов должен вернуть то же самое, что и первый, у компилятора может не хватать

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (this->search_buffer.size() == 0)
> {
>     current_element = nullptr;
>
>     return false;
> }
> else if (this->search_buffer.size() > 0)
> {
>     current_element = nullptr;
>
>     return true;
> }
> ```

```
current_element = nullptr;
return this->search_buffer.size();
```